# Android Expandable RecyclerView with 2 columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

i need to create a custom list view like in image below.

[image]

My idea is to use expandable recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager.
The problem is that this list has 2 columns and i dont know how to create expandable childs with full width like in image.

Have any ideas?

Thanks ))